Postman not sending @requestparams to spring application, but it works if i manually type the url in
I am trying to implement pagination in my spring application,however I am using @requestParams. Howver Postman is unable to send the parameters to my get methods which results in them picking the default value assigned.
I have tried rewriting the parameters multiple times, however if i type the entire link with the request params in the link then it works
this is my get method
@GetMapping("/api/public/categories")
public ResponseEntity<CategoryResponse> getallcategories(
    @RequestParam(name = "Page_number", defaultValue = Appconstants.PAGE_NUMBER,required = false) Integer pagenumber,
    @RequestParam(name = "Page size", defaultValue = Appconstants.PAGE_SIZE,required = false) Integer pgsize,
    @RequestParam(name = "Sortfield", defaultValue = Appconstants.SORT_CATEGORIES_BY, required = false) String sortby,
    @RequestParam(name = "sortorder", defaultValue = Appconstants.SORT_DEFAULT, required = false) String sortorder
) {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(
      cate.getallcategories(pagenumber, pgsize, sortby, sortorder),
      HttpStatus.OK
  );
}

this is the full url
http://localhost:8080/api/public/products
this is an example of my request](https://i.sstatic.net/pzx7OPwf.png)
When i type the url like this it works

You are sending headers not request parameters and second the names don't match (they need to match the name as mentioned in the @RequestParam annotation not the name of the field). .

First of all your api is /api/public/categories but you are trying to request api/public/products
When you build your app and sending a get request from a browser like below you have to get success response.


The parameter name that you request must match the name field in the @RequestParam annotation.

Remove empty character inside of name field
   @RequestParam(name = "Page_size", defaultValue = Appconstants.PAGE_SIZE,required = false) Integer pgsize,
